# HTML5 Video play/small etc buttons refresh?

Tags: asp.net, html, video

I am trying to create a ASP.NET page and using some HTML5 on it. Most of it from the example at w3schools.

*edit*
I use chrome as my primary testing browser. Both mp4 and ogg dont work in firefox, and the entire video tag doesnt work in ie8. Since i use xp, ie9 is impossible. If needed, i could instal opera or safari... Let me know if it helps.

**The Code:**

```
<div> 
<video id="movieid" width="420">
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="oggbestand.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
<p>Als uw browser te oud is, word deze melding weergegeven. Excuses voor het ongemak!</p>
</video>
<button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
<button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
<button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
<button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
<br /> 
</div>  

<script>
function playPause() {
var myVideo = document.getElementById("movieid");
if (myVideo.paused)
myVideo.play();
else
myVideo.pause();
}
function makeBig() {
var myVideo = document.getElementById("movieid");
myVideo.width = 560;
}
function makeSmall() {
var myVideo = document.getElementById("movieid");
myVideo.width = 320;
}
function makeNormal() {
var myVideo = document.getElementById("movieid");
myVideo.width = 420;
} 
</script>
```

**The problem:**
The four buttons above seem to work. However, somehow the page refreshed or something, returning the video to its original size. 
Could anyone help me with this problem, or even solve it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you click a button you will trigger a postback,
so what happens here is that you are running some javascript code that edit your HTML but then trigger a complete postback which will give you a completely new HTML page.

easy fix: add "return false;"

```
<button onclick="playPause(); return false;">Play/Pause</button> 
<button onclick="makeBig(); return false;">Big</button>
<button onclick="makeSmall(); return false;">Small</button>
<button onclick="makeNormal(); return false;">Normal</button>
```